# prevent method to be overwritten by scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm dealing with the fact that the UseDatabaseNames flag has been removed in Core 2.0, but globally i'm satisfied of the scaffolding.

But I've some methods to override / integrate each time I make the scaffolding to update models.

Is it a way to :

- either *protect* some methods to be changed / deleted by the scaffolding
- or flagging the scaffolding to be incremental ( only add new properties / classes )

Thank you all

Comment: Use a partial class and keep there the methods you want to keep between scaffoldings.

Comment: This works for methods which are not overwritten, but not for methods recreated on each scaffolding. For instance *protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)*

Comment: Sounds like you want feature request [#831](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831)

Comment: Yes its exactly that, thank you. Waiting...